# How to use SuperGLUE with huggingface-transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I would like to use SuperGLUE tasks with huggingface-transformers. Looking at this page:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/README.md

The only useful script is "run_glue.py". But I'm searching for "run_superglue.py", that I suppose it doesn't exist.

Did anyone try to use SuperGLUE tasks with huggingface-transformers? Maybe modifying "run_glue.py" adapting it to SuperGLUE tasks? Thanks